# Find substring in Photoshop document name

Tags: javascript, action, document, photoshop

I'm very new to Javascript and trying to create a script that will run an action if it finds a particular set of characters in the open document's name. Right now I've got this which doesn't do anything, but I think it might be on the right track?

```
var name = activeDocument.name

var mRP = "mrp"
var hits = []

for(var i = 0 ; i < name.length ; i++){
    if(name[i] === mRP[0]){
         for(var j = i ; j < i + mRP.length ; j++){
             if(name.substring(j, j + mRP.length)===mRP)

             hits.push(name.substring(j, j + mRP.length));

        }
    }
if(hits[0] === "mrp"){
app.doAction ('Make Crease', 'MR P')
}

}
```

I'm looking for the action to run if it finds *mrp* in the document's title.. usually structured like *BC342D_mrp_cu*

Answer (score 1):

You can search through the `activeDocument.name` string using regular expression and just do your action every time it finds `"mrp"` substring.

```
var name = activeDocument.name

var regex = /mrp/gi;

while ( regex.exec(name) )
    app.doAction ('Make Crease', 'MRP');
```

Here is fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g3hnnf3o/

Comment: Hi Zavg, thanks for your reply. 

**Edit:** Is this supposed to replace the entire code or go somewhere in it? I've tried running it just on its own and it doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry, didn't realise hitting enter submits the comment. The code doesn't seem to work?

Comment: Check out the fiddle! I have just added the link

Comment: Sorry, still a little confused. I've put your code into Adobe's ExtendScript Toolkit to test it and whenever I run it it just comes back with _Result: Undefined_

Comment: I don't know what your `app.doAction` does, but it seems that the error is within this command.

Comment: Yeah, maybe, although when I run it on its own, it runs the action fine...weird..

Comment: Does anybody know how to get this working? I've used the below code, but it doesn't seem to trigger the action:

`var name = activeDocument.name

var regex = /mrp/gi;

while ( regex.exec(name) )
    app.doAction ('Make Crease', 'MR P');
   `

However, when I run this on its own the actions runs fine..

`app.doAction ('Make Crease', 'MR P');`